# How do i get selected value and text without triggering mat-select MatSelectChange event in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In my html file i have this

```
  <mat-select placeholder="Job Category" formControlName="job_category" 
  (selectionChange)="selectedJobType($event)">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let job of jobTypes" [value]="job.jobid">
                {{ job.jobname }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
```

In .ts file i have

```
 jobRegisterForm = this.fb.group({
  job_category: [null, Validators.required]});
```

and in ngOnInit() i am setting my value with some id

this.jobRegisterForm.get('job_category').setValue(this.jobData.jobcategoryid);

So after this the value is displaying correctly in the dropdown.

So if the user changes the dropdown value i will get that value and its text using below code in my typescript

```
selectedJobType(event: MatSelectChange) {
    this.selectedMatJob = {
  value: event.value,
  text: event.source.triggerValue
   };
  }
```

But incase if the user not changing the dropdown value and he clicks on save of this form, so in that case to get '**job_category**' selected text and value what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

you can subscribe to valueChanges

```
//after create the form

this.jobRegisterForm.get('job_category').valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
    this.selectedMatJob = {
        value: res,
        text: this.jobType.find(j=>j.jobid==res).jobname
   };
})
//give value
this.jobRegisterForm.get('job_category').setValue(this.jobData.jobcategoryid);
```

Or you can use as "value" the own job

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let job of jobTypes" [ngValue]="job">
```

Then you need use [compareWith](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect),

```
<mat-select [formControl]="job_category" required [compareWith]="compare">
   ....
</mat-select>
```

And in your .ts

```
compare=(a:any,b:any)=>a.jobid==b.jobid//declare the function
//when give value you write, e.g.
const job=this.jobTypes.find(j=>jobid==this.jobData.jobcategoryid)
this.jobRegisterForm.get('job_category').setValue(job)
```

Yes, a FormControl can store an object

NOTE: really you need a function compareWith if you directly assign a value of an object of this.jobTypes as I do it using "find". But it's good know that using this compareWith you can use some like

```
this.jobRegisterForm.get('job_category').setValue(
  {jobid:1,jobname:'my first work'}
)
```

BTW, can be unnecesary each change get the value, you can only in submit add the category but it's only an opinion